# Is it possible to display and update a progress bar from the main thread?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, dm-script

I would like to pose a progress bar to show the status of a lengthy routine. It's rather straight forward to launch a dialog with progress bar from a background thread. However, is it possible to do so from a "foreground" process? The idea is to show the progress status but blocking user from doing anything with DM.

The built-in Progress gadget palette (accessible via the **OpenAndSetProgressWindow** script command) serves my purpose but I want to have a fancier interface and also to display more information. The following is an example script. As we can see that when posing the ProgressBar dialog from a foreground process, it is not updated at all.

```
class ProgressBar : UIFrame {
    number true, false;
    string Identifier_Status, identifier_progressBar;
    string panel_name;
    number token;
    //
    ProgressBar(object self) {;
        true=1; false=0;
        identifier_progressBar = "Progress_Bar";
        Identifier_Status = "Progress_Status"
        result("Script object \"ProgressBar\"[" + self.ScriptObjectGetID().hex() + "] constructed\n" );
    };
    ~ProgressBar(object self) {;
        result("Script object \"ProgressBar\"[" + self.ScriptObjectGetID().hex() + "] destructed\n\n" );
    };
    //
    void SetProgress(object self, number fraction) {
        self.DLGSetProgress( identifier_progressBar, fraction );
    };
    void UpdateStatus(object self, string status ) {
        self.LookUpElement(Identifier_Status).DLGTitle(status);
    };
    void Terminate(object self) {
        panel_name.CloseGadgetPanel();
        // token.UnregisterScriptPalette();
        panel_name.UnregisterScriptPalette();
    };

    void init(object self, string title, string prompt) {
        panel_name = title;
        // build main dialog tag group
        TagGroup tgDLG = DLGCreateDialog( panel_name );
        // create UIFrame elements
        TagGroup tgProgressBar = DLGCreateProgressBar(identifier_progressBar).DLGFill("X");
        TagGroup tgStatus = DLGCreateLabel(prompt).DLGWidth(40).DLGIdentifier(Identifier_Status);
        // build position
        TagGroup tgPositon = DLGBuildPositionFromApplication();
        tgPositon.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Width", "Wide" );        // Narrow, Medium, Wide;
        tgPositon.DLGSide( "Left" );
        tgDLG.DLGPosition(tgPositon);
        // assemble dialog
        tgDLG.DLGAddElement(tgStatus);
        tgDLG.DLGAddElement(tgProgressBar);
        // initialize and display
        self.super.init( tgDLG );
        token = self.RegisterScriptPalette(panel_name, panel_name);
        panel_name.OpenGadgetPanel();
        //
        return;
    };
};

class main : Thread {
    object obj;
    main(object self) {
        obj = alloc(ProgressBar);
        result("Script object \"main\"[" + self.ScriptObjectGetID().hex() + "] constructed\n" );
    };

    ~main(object self ) {
        result("Script object \"main\"[" + self.ScriptObjectGetID().hex() + "] destructed\n" );
    };

    void RunThread(object self) {
        obj.init( "Progress bar test", "<status>" );
        string msg1, msg2, msg3;
        number time = 5, interval = 0.1, nSteps = time/interval;
        for( number idx = 1; idx <= nSteps; idx++) {
            //
            msg1 = "Processing step:";
            msg2 = " ";
            msg3 = "#" + idx + " of " + nSteps;
            //
            OpenAndSetProgressWindow( msg1, msg2, msg3 );
            //
            obj.UpdateStatus( msg1 + msg2 + msg3  );
            obj.SetProgress( idx/nSteps );
            yield();
            sleep(interval);
        };
        msg1 = ""; msg3 = "";
        msg2 = "completed"
        OpenAndSetProgressWindow( msg1, msg2, msg3 );
        obj.Terminate();
    };
};

if( TwoButtonDialog( "Show and update progress bar as", "background thread", "forground process") ) alloc(main).StartThread();
else alloc(main).RunThread();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `DLGSetProgressBar()` form a main-thread, you need to force an update of the dialog-window with `ValidateView()`

i.e. in your script above you can do it either in the main-loop:

```
 void RunThread(object self) {
        obj.init( "Progress bar test", "<status>" );
        string msg1, msg2, msg3;
        number time = 5, interval = 0.5, nSteps = time/interval;
        for( number idx = 1; idx <= nSteps; idx++) {
            //
            msg1 = "Processing step:";
            msg2 = " ";
            msg3 = "#" + idx + " of " + nSteps;
            //
            OpenAndSetProgressWindow( msg1, msg2, msg3 );
            //
            Result("\n Step "+idx)
            obj.UpdateStatus( msg1 + msg2 + msg3  );
            obj.SetProgress( idx/nSteps );
            obj.ValidateView()                             // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
            yield();
            sleep(interval);
        };
        msg1 = ""; msg3 = "";
        msg2 = "completed"
        OpenAndSetProgressWindow( msg1, msg2, msg3 );
        obj.Terminate();
    };
```

Or you can do it in the update-method:

```
void SetProgress(object self, number fraction) {
    self.DLGSetProgress( identifier_progressBar, fraction );
    self.ValidateView()
};
```